# Dual rail power supply for audio needs to drive LED too, unsure of design approach

Tags: power-supply, power, led

I have a +17V, -17V power supply for a headphone amp I am building, I would like an LED to indicate when the amplifier is turned on, but don't want to negatively effect the audio output by drawing current from the same source.

Does someone maybe have some advice on how to power the LED?

Best regards
Andre

Comment: "but don't want to negatively effect the audio output by drawing current from the same source." Explain.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a small amount of DC current from your supply will have no effect on the audio. Your headphone amplifier will itself draw DC power from the supply to use internally.

Just use a series resistor. Since you have such a high voltage, pick an efficient LED and keep the current relatively low to save power- 1mA may enough for a good LED.

By the way, in your question, the word you want is **affect**.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a small amount of current to drive LED will not affect the output.

As per the Formula: `R = (Vs - Vf) / If`, a 14K series resistor with 3.3V forward voltage LED would work perfectly. Use this [calculator](https://www.digikey.in/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-led-series-resistor) for fine-tuning.